# How to create elasticsearch node client in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Wanted to know if anyone has created a node client for elasticsearch in python language. I am looking at elasticsearch-py documentation and its not very clear on node client creation part.

I have an elasticsearch cluster and have been loading several millions of records easily with the basic client. but now I need to load a billion records dataset, for which I am thinking to use node client

Comment: Node client is a Java Object, which cannot be created in python. Are you looking for a jython solution or you are searching for a way to start a client node from within your python script?

Comment: I am looking a way to create a client node from my python script itself

Answer (score 0):

You just need to start bin/elasticsearch script and pass it `-Des.node.client=true` as a parameter to indicate that this is a node client. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/dev-tools/create_bwc_index.py#L138)